# Firebase Firestore rules fails when using a sub model in collection - resource.data.model.submodel

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

So for example - the following rule will fail: `allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.creator.id;`

My collection is Tasks/{taskId}
Where task contains:

```
{
  "Title",
  // Creator is An object which contains the user who created it:
  "Creator": {
    "email",
    "id"
  }
}
```

So for the above example it will not allow the user to update it even if the user **is** the creator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it is not written in the official documentation but the way I solved this is:
`allow update if: request.auth.uid == resource.data.creator.data.id;`

Notice the resource.**data**.creator.**data**.id so for each sub document we must specify **data** again.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Gal's answer, here is an example for a more complex path with userId.

Collection: `/Projects/{projectId}`

Data: `users.{userId}.active` == true

Rule: `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Projects/$(projectId)).‌​data.users.data[(req‌​uest.auth.uid)].data‌​.active`